# Accessing data in a multidimensional JSON array with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I am trying to work out how to access data in an essentially multidimensional JSON array.

My jQuery AJAX request looks like this:

```
 $("#login-form").submit(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '/ajax/login',
   data: 'email='+$("#email").val()+'&password='+$("#password").val(),
   success: function(data){

     // FIRE ALERT HERE        
     alert(data.firstname);

     },
     dataType: 'json'
  });
});
```

This is what i am getting back. User account details, plus a list of products they have against their account.

```
{
    "logged_in":true,
    "firstname":"Joe",
    "surname":"Bloggs",
    "Full_name":"Joe Bloggs",
    "email":"email@website.com",
    "phone":"+123456789",
    "website":"",
    "age":"26-35",
    "street":"1 Street Ave",
    "city":"Townland",
    "state":"NA",
    "postcode":"1234",
    "country":"Australia",
    "products":2,
    "0":{
        "product_no":"1087",
        "customer":"2",
        "bought_from":"1",
        "date_of_purchase":"2011-04-08",
        "method":"instore",
        "invoice":"0",
        "current":"1"
    },
    "1":{
        "product_no":"24",
        "customer":"2",
        "bought_from":"1",
        "date_of_purchase":"2011-04-08",
        "method":"instore",
        "invoice":"0",
        "current":"1"
    }
}
```

As you can see, i am alerting the first name, which is fine. I can access everything in the first dimension by using data.key but i'm not sure how then i need to index the next dimension. Obviously I would like to display each of the products somehow.

Suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: if u r using *php* then `json_encode` is best solution for your data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your success function you can treat the JSON data as a JavaScript object. You can access the product array and objects inside it like this:

```
console.log(data.products + " product(s) in data"); // data.products is 2 (integer)
for(var i = 0; i < data.products; i++) {            // 
    var product = data[i.toString()];               // 0.toString() is "0"
                                                    // data["0"] is what you want
                                                    // now product points to the property "0"
    console.log(product.product_no);                // so you can use product.xxx
                                                    // or product["xxx"]
}                                                   // likewise for "1", "2", "3" and so on
```

Replace `console.log` with `alert` if you do not know what console is.

Comment: `data.products.length` returns `undefined` bcoz that "0" and "1" are not the child of `products`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for poitning me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Each of the product details can be accessed through `data[iProductIndex.toString()]` member. Data is stored inside `data["0"]` and `data["1"]`, therefore to access them you need to convert integer value to string. Unfortunately you won't be able to use `$.each` loop because "0" and "1" are separate member objects. Use for loop with `iProductIndex`.

Comment: Any chance of a little example? I'm relatively new to jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Data supplied does not allow for your answer, Salman A. See [JSON Arrays](http://json.org/js.html) for array definition, to have it work your way it must've been defined as

```
{"products" : [ {"product_no":"1087",
        "customer":"2",
        "bought_from":"1",
        "date_of_purchase":"2011-04-08",
        "method":"instore",
        "invoice":"0",
        "current":"1"} ] }
```

To OP:
alert(data["0"].product_no);
alert(data["1"]["date_of_purchase"]);

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var json_string={
    "logged_in":true,
    "firstname":"Joe",
    "surname":"Bloggs",
    "Full_name":"Joe Bloggs",
    "email":"email@website.com",
    "phone":"+123456789",
    "website":"",
    "age":"26-35",
    "street":"1 Street Ave",
    "city":"Townland",
    "state":"NA",
    "postcode":"1234",
    "country":"Australia",
    "products":2,
    "0":{
        "product_no":"1087",
        "customer":"2",
        "bought_from":"1",
        "date_of_purchase":"2011-04-08",
        "method":"instore",
        "invoice":"0",
        "current":"1"
    },
    "1":{
        "product_no":"24",
        "customer":"2",
        "bought_from":"1",
        "date_of_purchase":"2011-04-08",
        "method":"instore",
        "invoice":"0",
        "current":"1"
    }
};

for (key in json_string) {
// Most modern browsers should have hasOwnProperty by now.
// This keeps us from getting farther up the chain.
if (json_string.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
document.write(key + "->" + json_string[key]);
document.write("<br>");
}
}; 


var pro_1= json_string[0]; // here u change 0 with 1 and get the data of "1"

for (key in pro_1) {
if (pro_1.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
document.write(key + "->" + pro_1[key]);
document.write("<br>");
}
}; 

</script>
```