# Nested JSON-object in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, json, serialization

I want to create a multidimensional json object based on a c# class. I normally do it like this:

```
public class foo
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

And serialize a new instance of the class with a JavaScriptSerializer. But lets say that i want to add another json array containing the persons friends inside the main json array. Example array: [Accessing data in a multidimensional JSON array with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617496/accessing-data-in-a-multidimensional-json-array-with-jquery)

Hope you get the idea. Thanks

Comment: What you asking for isn't an array. It is a hash objects with properties named "0", "1", etc. If that is what you want, then that is how you should define your foo class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question corect, something like this should work...

```
public class Person 
{     
  public string name { get; set; }     
  public int age { get; set; } 
  public List<Person> Friends { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating the JSON version of your class, foo?

[JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) and [Controller.JSON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504936.aspx) (in MVC) support serializing IEnumerable derived types, so you could have the class:

```
public class foo
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public List<Bar> friends {get; set;}
}
```

and your JSON serialized class would include the list of Bar objects.

Comment: Im just creating a new instance of the class, adding some values, and go something like `new JavaScriptSerializer.serialize(object)`. So you got my point and your answer is correct as well. Thanks for answering but ill accept YWes since he posted first :)